# How to extract summary statistics from sm.regression?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, smoothing

I am using `sm.regression` function from package `sm` to complete my university assignment and came across a couple of questions that I can't find answers to online.

**The task is:**

Fit a bivariate smooth term using kernel smoothing in two dimensions for a response Y and a bivariate term between X and Z. A very high smoothing parameter should be used for X to force a linear relationship while the level of smoothness for Z should be determined based on visualising the data.

**My code:**

```
require(sm)
x  <- cbind(Z,X)
y  <- Y
LL <- sm.regression(x,y,h=c(3,15))
```

Setting the second smoothing parameter to be 15 ensures that a linear relationship is forced.

**Question:**

How do I obtain goodness of fit statistics such as RSS, degrees of freedom for the model. In general, how do I extract the usual bits like fitted values, residuals, estimated effective degrees of freedom for the smooth term etc?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

As a request in comments:

**dput(x)**

```
structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1.82454929205105, 1.39252491087053, 
0.993251773010283, 0.587786664902119, 1.12330490125848, 1.12330490125848, 
1.53686721959926, 3.99314205671294, 3.51551763869145, 2.21648239394063, 
1.50407739677627, 1.3415584672785, NA, NA, 2.20092143921755, 
1.22377543162212, 2.11625551480255, 2.65558663156647, 3.54769984065116, 
4.2579739860039, 2.83321334405622, 2.87919845729804, 2.58021682959233, 
NA, NA, 1.51512723296286, 2.19165353228676, 2.24601474150565, 
1.48160454092422, 1.66770682055808, 4.1268117523596, 3.50930412298801, 
2.67000213346468, 3.23212105161822, 2.88666117849963, 2.81839825827108, 
2.86505394991188, 2.29000631078719, 1.69101789942652, 0.113328685307003, 
0.765467842139571, 0.799756915618204, 0.553885113226438, 1.88327457806383, 
3.59676416520613, 1.90210752639692, 1.42911435830282, 1.50407739677627, 
3.43720781918519, 2.45958884180371, 1.43508452528932, 1.26694760348732, 
0.662687973075237, 0.545227050483323, 2.78037086268184, 2.96320908184843, 
2.60268968544438, 2.87638551592142, 3.13549421592915, 3.49650756146648, 
3.41772668361337, 2.22462355152433, 1.34373474670109, 1.09861228866811, 
1.19392246847243, 0.485507815781701, 1.70474809223843, 4.09933210373314, 
4.39906810052873, 3.28091121578765, 2.95751106073379, 2.95751106073379, 
2.85647020622048, 1.87180217690159, 0.693147180559945, 1.01160091167848, 
0.916290731874155, 1.98787434815435, 1.67896397508271, 3.13331793650655, 
4.11984985263046, 3.39450839351136, 2.69799986524871, 2.39789527279837, 
0.955511445027436, 1.48160454092422, 1.2947271675944, 1.19392246847243, 
1.38629436111989, 1.1314021114911, 1.31908561142644, 2.98315349134713, 
3.45757771509826, 2.04122032885964, 1.38629436111989, 1.06471073699243, 
1.71079040669439, 1.14740245283754, 1.19392246847243, 1.7227665977411, 
1.26694760348732, 1.01523067972906, 1.11514159061932, 1.90954250488444, 
1.64222773525709, 1.48160454092422, 1.71379792775834, 0.8754687373539, 
1.2947271675944, 1.45083288225746, 1.06471073699243, 0.8754687373539, 
1.17865499634165, 1.29746314741327, 2.484906649788, 1.50407739677627, 
1.38128181929635, 0.53062825106217, 0.717839793150317, 1.31730148963294, 
1.26694760348732, 1.20896034583698, 1.63413052502447, 0.916290731874155, 
1.43983512804792, 0.8754687373539, 1.22377543162212, 2.83673654206353, 
2.9391619220656, 1.73165554515835, 1.77495235091167, 2.9882040071332, 
2.71137799119488, 1.88706964903238, 1.80005827204275, 1.57897870494939, 
2.05412373369555, 1.42310833424261, 1.62268313918412, 1.64865862558738, 
1.82454929205105, 2.3764549415605, 2.71137799119488, 2.16332302566054, 
1.35239280944421, 1.26694760348732, 1.17865499634165, 1.16315080980568, 
0.916290731874155, 1.32175583998232, 2.01490302054226, 1.88706964903238, 
2.01490302054226, 2.71137799119488, 1.53686721959926, 0.624154309072996, 
0.8754687373539, 0.916290731874155, 1.25276296849537, 1.69193913394584, 
1.26694760348732, 2.79116510781272, 2.77570884957602, 3.24649099190117, 
3.09874002362822, 2.22462355152433, 1.97408102602201, 2.61739583283408, 
1.76644166124377, 1.43508452528932, 1.85629799036563, 1.81645208181843, 
1.99470031322475, 2.23001440015921, 2.42480272571829, 3.78418963391826, 
3.63098547569503, 2.72457950305342, 2.29556047805708, 3.35165693610202, 
3.4291367503514, 2.65675690671466, 1.87946504964716, 2.3887627892351, 
2.06686275947298, 2.18041745901984, 2.52172062291072, 3.24454357161678, 
2.80638610182307, 1.45861502269952, 2.05796251000271, 2.02154756326093, 
1.50407739677627, 1.44691898293633, 1.67709656090792, 1.85629799036563, 
1.98375629154543, 2.05412373369555, 2.8094026953625, 3.73169945129686, 
2.2082744135228, 1.79674701073909, 1.69561560867515, 2.24601474150565, 
2.3664984187377, 1.48160454092422, 1.14740245283754, 1.3609765531356, 
1.57069708411767, 1.00430160919687, 0.85015092936961, 1.36353737399727, 
1.69927861643389, 1.70474809223843, 2.40061883326541, 2.75493378700106
), .Dim = c(216L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Month", "LSRP"
)))
```

**dput(y)**

```
c(3.70696492166032, 4.06817168791808, 3.79548918917219, 3.19581188526965, 
1.92861865194525, 2.86105737022739, 4.28606624352797, 3.49438409638827, 
4.12987256828125, 4.33833594604915, 4.44769732716353, 4.50865928560725, 
NA, NA, 3.09693415406296, 3.22207071576472, 2.35137525716348, 
3.16251709119882, 3.67604747529856, 4.04830062372069, 3.56388296393925, 
3.93671561801852, 3.00667221359233, NA, NA, 2.50959926237837, 
2.56109578814555, 3.40452517175483, 3.71600812150219, 4.69984379959077, 
4.01439907204501, 3.95680514820004, 4.16759502396169, 2.67414864942653, 
3.13679771383259, 2.63260800593535, 2.77633170851862, 3.3261145755378, 
3.61199840977798, 3.41477150168927, 2.63476240533238, 2.51608226725645, 
3.33967652501391, 4.13212192655613, 4.23555473077362, 4.45166929500233, 
4.13436623657159, 4.01186834039786, 3.17596832385692, 4.08916450218056, 
4.38215162686203, 4.19705156041436, 4.43378856923247, 5.13037197569859, 
5.04271518755967, 4.60487014097909, 4.03618564804857, 2.55334381134123, 
2.58399755243223, 2.27418561847235, 2.27521389619791, 3.21687382219753, 
3.93671561801852, 3.05305734017326, 2.47401420862158, 2.96630346286318, 
3.76930670322655, 4.70555836001936, 2.7434173449395, 2.76316950032329, 
2.90306858869057, 2.56725439113675, 2.68444033546308, 3.15700042115011, 
4.34055338646731, 3.2604015716967, 2.39607543608138, 2.46725171454928, 
3.38065448043083, 3.75396470076987, 3.69062792464805, 3.3178157727231, 
3.2104403460471, 3.58518421777517, 3.72086249996699, 4.34510328056928, 
3.68260984110034, 3.41608599415591, 3.48584485572244, 3.35620001573142, 
3.55962461825667, 4.10280864063423, 3.73002139744511, 3.94487734229909, 
4.03193710209348, 3.95469927970858, 3.92157721823296, 4.05352256770185, 
3.89487684659318, 3.91342202634185, 2.91506437048654, 2.95595140354215, 
3.63705970538414, 3.84074180342318, 3.79863031807306, 3.89365534806996, 
3.94255221046297, 4.24348270022581, 4.52135369989498, 4.29496980210571, 
4.13612609623706, 4.15182699763546, 4.06817168791808, 3.74856245627511, 
3.54673968695281, 3.81220267014594, 3.51273875639506, 3.62593965434006, 
3.65402917667819, 3.44712631355056, 3.2561716096119, 3.22286784613774, 
3.45062226498968, 3.18841661738349, 2.10778601468898, 2.4923786646267, 
3.56274917696972, 3.54932998916385, 3.5801800371906, 4.30730308847795, 
4.33362389544571, 3.28391422104742, 2.86789890204411, 3.73337469400049, 
3.56444937573576, 3.24571247882176, 2.11625551480255, 1.80170980008122, 
2.01756613796175, 3.62620585958588, 3.82319179172153, 3.90741239287046, 
2.86619290219901, 3.43559880837949, 4.04795152265239, 4.04742764243435, 
3.88629485685541, 3.08328517056185, 3.10324048126928, 3.64309726145881, 
2.71071331852169, 3.56953269648137, 3.37211180076706, 3.30688670219091, 
3.71940865914876, 4.08631239052484, 4.0926765051214, 3.03495298670727, 
3.5418285114019, 3.4797004431501, 3.39886132186461, 2.32238772029023, 
3.56784112573688, 3.7864597824528, 3.83859172734226, 3.88957287659055, 
3.74194617505063, 3.67554088967476, 3.79211270875559, 4.00241200515583, 
3.42588999425253, 3.1776370768516, 2.006870848845, 2.06305806242931, 
2.70404217970467, 3.55105313720653, 4.14535448312985, 4.9098568572557, 
4.58598736657132, 3.24024585060439, 2.43624147780672, 3.31745338822919, 
3.77940548081331, 3.72930136861285, 2.77196352684586, 2.92530980925744, 
3.58073729549423, 3.86807111789896, 3.82100360704098, 4.36335336940826, 
3.8264651170665, 2.4466854369678, 3.1540172525197, 3.02286094094224, 
2.81540871942271, 3.34356826882552, 2.43361335540045, 2.31451366385932, 
4.20871437203751, 4.13660552093661, 3.93456696986304, 4.28592864462854, 
3.2188758248682, 3.10906095886099, 3.38777436133001, 3.38371206732114, 
2.88368276974537, 1.90210752639692, 2.14826773260969, 2.52572864430826, 
3.99599643920432, 3.21687382219753, 3.65919314374358, 3.41378449716763, 
3.17178421733435, 3.69635146895264)
```

Comment: You'll want to check out the package `broom`

Comment: Just did! @ZheyuanLi

Comment: `broom` looks like a great package for future reference, however in this case it returns : `Error in tidy.list(LL) : No tidying method recognized for this list` @JakeKaupp

Comment: My apologies, I thought it included a tidy method for `sm`.